# How to search for two values in array at the same time?

Tags: jquery, arrays, jquery-select2, dropdown

I have a select2 dropdown on my page that is populated with countries from a table in my database. A user is able to select more than one country, forming an array. I want to search for two values in the array.  For example:

```
    var selvalues = $(this).val(); //["AS", "US", "CA"]
```

On the change event of the dropwdown, If "US" is one of the values and the array also contains a value that is not the "US", throw an error.

Some of the things that I have tried so far in jQuery:

```
$('#countriesSelect').on('change', function(){

    var selvalues = $(this).val(); 

   console.log(selvalues .some(x => x !== 'US' && x == 'US'));

   if(selvalues.includes('US') || !selvalues.includes('US')){
        console.log('You cannot choose a foreign country when current selection is US');  
    }
   if($.inArray("US",selvalues) != -1){
        $('#usregions').show().fadeIn();
        if($.inArray("US",selvalues) != -1){}
    } else {
        $('#usregions').hide().fadeOut();
    }
    $.each(selvalues, function( index, value ) {
        console.log()
        if(value == 'US' && value != 'US'){
            console.log('You cannot choose a foreign country when current selection is US');   
        } 
    });
});
```

I expect to have it to throw an error based on the above criteria.

Answer (score 2):

Work the logic.  It's an error if you select `US` and something else.  Meaning you have at least two selections, one of which being `US`.  So you do not care what the others are, so long as there are multiple and one is the `US`.

```
if (selvalues.length > 1 && selvalues.includes('US')) { ...problem... }
```

Comment: True. Ugh, it pains me when I was so close.  Just reminds me that I have to try to slow down when faced with a logic problem.